# What could be the cause of a limit in the voltage supplied to a capacitor?

Tags: solenoid, electrolytic-capacitor, back-emf

Recently I built a very basic 2-stage coil gun for a school project. Each coil was powered by an electrolytic capacitor. In order to charge the capacitor, the coil connected to an IGBT (insulated-gate bipolar transistor). I controlled that would block the current during charging. When I wished to shoot the coil I would use an Arduino to open the IGBT and then discharge the capacitor through the coil.

There was also a diode to help protect the IGBT but I don't believe this was the source of the problem I faced. I also later learned that my diode didn't properly protect my IGBT, I am aware of my mistake in that regard and am only including it incase this is somehow the source of my problem.

My capacitor was rated for 80 volts and had 0.1 farads of capacitance. I charged it to 70 volts to be safe but after the first discharge I was unable to charge it past 36 volts. After a decent amount of analysis I could not find a reason why this happened so I tried charging and discharging more times to see if I could find a pattern but it would simply plateau at arbitrarily low voltages without any clear pattern.

I also noticed that when taken off the charger it would very slowly but noticeably leak voltage. I charged the capacitor with a fixed power supply that outputted 100 volts but used a rheostat to ensure the current did not get too high, and a multimeter to ensure I did not surpass 70 volts across the capacitor. Both the power supply and multimeter seemed to be working well when tested without the capacitor involved.

After speaking to my professor about it, he theorized that I damaged the capacitor due to the fast discharge but I was wondering if there is another possible reason I hit certain voltage plateaus or how to avoid this problem in the future if this is the reason. Below is a picture of my circuit of one coil(the two coils are isolated but follows the same set up).

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if your IGBT is damaged?  Can you remove the cap or at least one lead of the cap to see if you can charge it up in isolation?

Comment: @JohnD Because this was a project for school that had to be presented I ended up soldering the the circuit together. Because of this I believe I did damage the IGBT during the soldering of it and was also unable to charge the capacitor in isolation. I'm not sure how this would affect the charge though as I could still charge this to 30 or once 60 volts in later attempts. Because of this I did not further investigate the damaged IGBT or isolated capacitor.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712637/2451